# Laravel 8: How to fix ParseError syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I know this question may sound stupid, but I'm working with Laravel, and I want to return an alert message for one of my route which is placed inside of a group route:

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('profile', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile'){
        alert()->success('welcome','message')->persistent('Ok');
    }
    Route::get('profile/twofactor', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'manageTwoFactor'])->name('profile.2fa.manage');
    Route::post('profile/twofactor', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'postManageTwoFactor']);
});
```

As you can see for the route `profile` I have set this message but I get `ParseError syntax error, unexpected ';'`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in a proper way.

So if you know, please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: as error says you forgot to put ; after your Route alerts end

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov If you mean this line: `alert()->success('welcome','message')->persistent('Ok');`, then it is ended with `;`

Comment: not there check thisRoute::get('profile', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile'){
        alert()->success('welcome','message')->persistent('Ok');
    };  here

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov No man! I have tried that one, but didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that line:

```
Route::get('profile', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile'){
    alert()->success('welcome','message')->persistent('Ok');
}
```

You have curly braces around `alert()...`, that is mistake.

You should change it to:

```
Route::get('profile', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
```

And move `alert()->success('welcome','message')->persistent('Ok');` to the index method of the ProfileController class.